LXDE panel gets cut off on Ubuntu 24.04
I made a clean install of LXDE on Ubuntu 24.04 on my VPS, and the panel (taskbar) appears cut off. Furthermore, each time more things are displayed in the panel, the panel gets longer and longer, and finally it sticks out.
This problem did not occur on Ubuntu 22.04.
The installation had been done just in the following steps.
$ sudo apt -y update
$ sudo apt -y upgrade
$ sudo apt install -y lxde-core xrdp

Version information:
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble

$ lxpanel --version
lxpanel 0.10.1

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Any help would be appreciated.


I have the same issue after installing RaspAP on my raspberry PI... it switched to LXDE instead of raspberry pi desktop (RPD)

Exact same issue here after upgrading from 23.10 to 24.04. It seems to be caused by the Desktop Pager applet.
If you open the Panel Preferences and remove Desktop Pager from the Panel Applets tab, the bar looks normal again. You can do that by right-clicking on the taskbar → Panel Preferences → select the Panel Applets tab → select Desktop Pager → click Remove.

Found that cause at: https://sourceforge.net/p/lxde/bugs/968/

Thanks for the helpful information!! I set it up as per your information and the problem seems to be solved!

Sorry, I noticed that the first problem, "panel cut off," has been resolved, but the second problem, "panel sticking out," is still not resolved.
To be more specific, when I launch various applications and the number of items in the "Task Bar (Window List)" increases, the "CPU Usage Monitor" and "Digital Clock" that were originally displayed on the right edge are pushed out of the screen and become invisible. This symptom has not been resolved after removing the Desktop Pager as described above.

Did you at some point have a 2nd monitor in use that the OS thinks might still be there?
edit: Hmm, same here, never used a 2nd monitor so that's not it.
